# The product of $100\times 2$ and $2\times 100$ matrices must have zero determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let A be a 100 × 2 matrix and let B be a 2 × 100 matrix. Then
C = AB is a 100 × 100 matrix. Explain why $\det(C) = 0$.

My initial thoughts on this question is that if $\det(C)=0$, then it cannot be expressed as the product of elementary matrices, which would be the case given that both A and B are not square, and hence they themselves cannot be expressed this way.

Is my line of thinking with this correct, or am I missing something glaringly obvious?

Comment: No, your line of thinking goes in a wrong direction; beginning by assuming what needs to be proved. The key concept to be used here is _rank_.

Comment: Pad $A$ with 80 columns of zeros to a $100 \times 100$ matrix $\tilde{A}$. Pad $B$ with 80 rows of zeros to a $100\times 100$ matrix $\tilde{B}$. Now $\tilde{A}\tilde{B} = AB = C$, this means....

Comment: oops, should be 98 columns and 98 rows. I hope you get it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

1. $rank(A_{m\times n})\le\min\{m,n\}=2$ (in this case)
2. $rank(A_{m\times n}B_{n\times m})\le\min\{rank(A),rank(B)\}\le2$ (in this case)

and
 3. if $rank(A_{n\times n})< n$, then $\det(A)=0$.

**Edit**: Since OP is yet to be introduced to the term "rank", adding from comments:

Let $\bar A_{100\times100}=\left[\begin{matrix} A_{100\times2} && 0_{100\times98}\end{matrix}\right]$, $\bar B_{100\times100}=\left[\begin{matrix} B_{2\times100} \\ 0_{98\times100}\end{matrix}\right]$

If $A=(a_{i,j})_{100\times2}$, $B=(b_{i,j})_{2\times100}$,

$\bar A$ will look like

$$\left[\begin{matrix} a_{1,1} && a_{1,2} && 0 && \cdots && 0 \\
a_{2,1} && a_{2,2} && 0 && \cdots && 0\\
\vdots && \vdots && \vdots && \vdots && \vdots &&\\
a_{100,1} && a_{100,2} && 0 && \cdots && 0\end{matrix}\right]$$

and $\bar B$ will look like

$$\left[\begin{matrix} b_{1,1} && b_{1,2} && \cdots && b_{1,100} \\
b_{2,1} && b_{2,2} && \cdots && b_{2,100} \\
0 && 0 && \cdots && 0\\
\vdots && \vdots && \vdots && \vdots &&\\
0 && 0 && \cdots && 0\end{matrix}\right]$$

Note that $\bar A\bar B=AB$, imagine number of zero rows in $AB$, and effect it will have on determinant.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with this concept of the rank of a matrix, as it is something that has not be covered in my course so far, do you my explaining what this is  supposed to mean.

Comment: Quoting google: "The rank of a matrix is defined as (a) the maximum number of linearly independent column vectors in the matrix or (b) the maximum number of linearly independent row vectors in the matrix. Both definitions are equivalent.". If you have any linear algebra text book, it should have the topic discussed in detail. Will surely edit the answer if I can think of any solutions not involving rank!

Comment: @Cameron, I have added achillehui's  idea into my answer, just for your understanding! Hopefully he will post it as a separate answer!

Comment: @JessePFrancis there is no point to replicate answer. as long as someone has written down the idea, it is enough.